# What is the C Equivalent of Python's pack("<I", 0)

Tags: python, c, endianness

I don't know much python but from what I can tell from the documentation the code:

```
   str = "AAAA"
   str += pack("<I", 0)
```

would append the result of the pack function to str, which would be the integer value of 0 in little-endian style. My question is what the C equivalent of this would be. Would it just be:

```
   char str[20] = "AAAA";
   strcat(str, "\x00");
```

?...

Comment: @icktoofay: You can, you just can't use normal string manipulation functions.

Comment: @Ignacio: By "ordinary" C string, I meant a string that works with the normal string manipulation functions. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat()` stops at the first NUL, so no.

```
char str[20] = "AAAA";
int val = 0;
int nval = htole32(val);
memcpy(str + 4, (char*)&nval, 4);
```