# C Equivalent of Python Code struct.pack?

Tags: python, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the C Equivalent of Python's pack(“<I”, 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771070/what-is-the-c-equivalent-of-pythons-packi-0)

How can I replicate the code in Python:

```
from struct import pack
string = pack("<I", 0x11111111)
print string
```

in C? From what I understand \x11 is a nonprintable character so...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char *string = "\x11\x11\x11\x11";
puts(string);
```

Comment: In Python, `print` will also print a newline, so it might be `printf("%s\n", string);` instead.

Comment: @icktoofay Ah - I don't know any python - thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

```
char* memory = (char*)malloc(5); //4 bytes plus null
for(uint i=0;i<4;i++){
  memory[i] = 0x11; //creating a little-endian 4byte \0x11111111 
  // avoiding local endianess issues
};
memory[4] = 0; //To make it into a string
printf("%s\n", memory);
free(memory);
```

Comment: There's little need to use `malloc()` here. It's easy to forget to `free()` the memory, as your example showed.

Comment: @GregHewgill Aw shucks. Spent too much time with GC'd languges :)
Still, I wrote it trying to fit the python code closely, so it's unclear what might be added to the mix after example's "<I", thus my use of malloc instead of static length.